# Receive raw response data using axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, axios

I am trying to receive the `raw` response data, not the response headers or body. As an example, an image here shows the tab where this data is found:

[image: The Developer Console]

Now, I am trying to receive this data when making an HTTP Request using `Axios`. Is this even possible?
I have tried searching online for about 2 hours, as this was a huge problem I was facing. I tried other sites, including stack overflow, to get the correct answer. If possible, could you please answer my question if you know? Thanks in advance.

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const url = 'https://old.reddit.com/api/login?user=username&passwd=password'
function axiosTest() {
    return axios.post(url).then((r) => {
        console.log(r)
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code or what have you tried?

Comment: I am using this to make a Reddit HTTP request, and am interacting with the API

Comment: The result is a lot of unnecessary data, including headers and the body.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the API and what's the response structure. Can you post the response here? Please mask any sensitive data

Comment: here: https://pastebin.com/L5UYxJQx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you must access the `data` property in the response object `r`. Also - since you are using the reddit API - make sure you are providing `api_type` in the request url (`api_type=json` for instance):

```
const axios = require('axios');
const url = 'https://old.reddit.com/api/login?api_type=json&user=username&passwd=password'
function axiosTest() {
    return axios.post(url).then((r) => {
        console.log(r.data)
        return r.data;
    })
}
```

For anyone reading this: Just to clarify, the `api_type` parameter in the request url is specific to the reddit API and most likely won't work any other API.

Comment: I already tried this, but it just returns
```javascript
{
  jquery: [
    [ 0, 1, 'call', [Array] ],
    [ 1, 2, 'attr', 'find' ],
    [ 2, 3, 'call', [Array] ],
    [ 3, 4, 'attr', 'hide' ],
    [ 4, 5, 'call', [] ],
    [ 5, 6, 'attr', 'html' ],
    [ 6, 7, 'call', [Array] ],
    [ 7, 8, 'attr', 'end' ],
    [ 8, 9, 'call', [] ]
  ],
  success: true
}
```

Comment: What response are you expecting? As you may noticed the `success` attribute in you response is `true`, which indicates that your login succeeded.
I'm not familiar with the reddit API...

Comment: I am expecting the raw response data, as shown in the picture above. Is it possible to retrieve this data?

Comment: Are you requesting the same URL in your screenshot? Also, are you using the same request method (POST)?
You can also compare the headers sent by the request from your browser with the ones your sending with axios (none as far as I can see).

Comment: I got that data using an XMLHttpRequest, and yes, I am using POST for both. The reason why I don't use XMLHttpRequest is because of CORS and XSS protection.

Comment: You have to provide `api_type=json` in the request url, this should fix it ;) I updated my answer above.

Comment: Thanks! What an obvious mistake of me.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help ;)